# How to change order items in autocomplete entity?

Tags: symfony-services

I override alter autocomplete in my custom module but I don't know how I can change the display order (DESC or ASC)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\alter_entity_autocomplete;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Tags;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAutocompleteMatcherInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionPluginManagerInterface;

/**
 * Matcher class to get autocompletion results for entity reference.
 */
class EntityAutocompleteMatcher implements EntityAutocompleteMatcherInterface
{

  /**
   * The entity reference selection handler plugin manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionPluginManagerInterface
   */
  protected $selectionManager;

  /**
   * Constructs an EntityAutocompleteMatcher object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionPluginManagerInterface $selection_manager
   *   The entity reference selection handler plugin manager.
   */
  public function __construct(SelectionPluginManagerInterface $selection_manager)
  {
    $this->selectionManager = $selection_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function getMatches($target_type, $selection_handler, $selection_settings, $string = '')
  {
    $matches = [];

    $options = $selection_settings + [
        'target_type' => $target_type,
        'handler' => $selection_handler,
      ];
    $handler = $this->selectionManager->getInstance($options);

    if (isset($string)) {
      // Get an array of matching entities.
      $match_operator = !empty($selection_settings['match_operator']) ? $selection_settings['match_operator'] : 'CONTAINS';
      $match_limit = isset($selection_settings['match_limit']) ? (int)$selection_settings['match_limit'] : 50;
      $entity_labels = $handler->getReferenceableEntities($string, $match_operator, $match_limit);

      // Loop through the entities and convert them into autocomplete output.
      foreach ($entity_labels as $values) {
        foreach ($values as $entity_id => $label) { 
          //->sort('id', 'DESC')
          $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($target_type)->load($entity_id);
          $entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($entity);

          $key = $label . ' (' . $entity_id . ')';
          // Strip things like starting/trailing white spaces, line breaks and tags.
          $key = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", '', trim(Html::decodeEntities(strip_tags($key)))));
          // Names containing commas or quotes must be wrapped in quotes.
          $key = Tags::encode($key);
          $label = $label . ' (' . $entity_id . ')';
          $matches[] = ['value' => $key, 'label' => $label];
        }
      }
    }

    return $matches;
  }

}
```

Can you help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you only have to reverse the `$matches` array, no? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Good idea i did it  return array_reverse($matches)

Thank you.